# how to put a button beside a dropdownlist in asp.net properly?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have dragged a (dropdownlist) and i try to add a button beside it, in the design view it is beside the (dropdownlist) but when i run it, i see a more than five space between them see the below code. i don't know what to do actually. i have tried to put them into a table one row with two columns but the space between them is quite a lot. i only want one space between them

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="280px">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

in design view 
[image]

in run mode
[image]

Comment: can you show a bit more here, like the container that these controls are in?

Comment: @Claies thank you very much you made me test it in new form and it worked in the new asp form, there must be something wrong with my Current asp form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all who have tried or wants to try answering this question by seeing the title
the problem with that is because i was given the (dropdownlist) CssClass="form-control" and it was not allowing the butten to be close to it resulting in giving it a few spaces
by changing the CssClass from (form-control) to CssClass="dropdown"), it solved my problem